# Why is this happening? (SharpFont / Monogame Error)

Tags: c#, arrays, monogame, freetype

I'm trying to get a MonoGame texture from a FreeType (SharpFont) bitmap.

If I use `Bitmap.ToGdipBitmap`, it works fine, but that seems very inefficient and hacky. When I try to convert it myself I get a `System.ArgumentException` (Source array was not long enough).

The code for `Bitmap.ToGdipBitmap` looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rec.rows; i++)
    PInvokeHelper.Copy(Buffer, i * rec.pitch, locked.Scan0, i * locked.Stride, rec.width);
```

and my code looks like this:

```
byte[] data = fontFace.Glyph.Bitmap.BufferData;
for (int y = 0; y < (int)glyphTexture.Height; y++)
{
    byte[] row = new byte[(int)glyphTexture.Width];
    Array.Copy(data, y * fontFace.Glyph.Bitmap.Pitch, row, 0, row.Length);
    ...
}
```

Mostly focusing on these two:

```
i * rec.pitch

y * fontFace.Glyph.Bitmap.Pitch
```

Wouldn't they both do basically the same thing?

Comment: "seems very inefficient and hacky" is not really an objective measure. How efficient to do need it to be? Do you actually have a real issue with how long it's taking to perform the operation? Have to measured anything? It's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: It's more that i'm wondering why it is happening even though i am doing  the same thing as Bitmap.ToGdipBitmap.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclosure** I'm the author of SharpFont.

`FTBitmap.ToGdipBitmap` was written with performance in mind. `PInvokeHelper.Copy` does per-byte copying on pointers, which should only be beat in performance by `Buffer.BlockCopy`, but that requires both the source and the destination to be arrays when both are currently just pointers to unmanaged memory. Other copy methods in C# like `Marshal.Copy` still require one side to be an array.

Your implementation involves at least twice as much memory copying (`Bitmap.BufferData` does a `Marshal.Copy`) and also stresses the GC by allocating a lot of small arrays.

The bit that you're focusing on looks fine, I'd say it's the width of your `glyphTexture` that's smaller than the FTBitmap's `pitch`, but that part of the code wasn't posted so I can't be completely sure without more information.

Comment: The error was actually a bug in Bitmap.BufferData, `rec.rows * rec.width` should have been `rec.rows * rec.pitch` but i see that it is fixed now.

Comment: ah well... guess that's what I get for trying to answer an old question while looking at current code :P